# Нужно ли обособлять оборот "к тому же"?

Tags: пунктуация

Выделяется ли запятыми оборот "к тому же": в начале, в середине и в конце предложения?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*К тому же* – союз, сам по себе не обособляется. Но выделяются запятыми присоединительные обороты, начинающиеся этим союзом, например: *Меж тем регулировщица, став перед полуторкой, ругала Хижняка, несомненного виновника затора, **к тому же** не желавшего осаживать назад, за обочину, на арестную площадку, как она требовала.*

Answer (score 2):

Согласна с предыдущим ответом, но следует дополнить его. "Я, к тому же, хорошо играю на пианино"-, в конструкциях подобного типа следует ставить запятую. и это уже не союз, а предлог+местоимение+частица, а в целом - синонимичное обособленному дополнению "кроме того"

Answer (score 0):

Вот что пишет Грамота.ру:

[>К ТОМУ ЖЕ, союз](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?id=58_384&layout=item)

> Присоединительные обороты, начинающиеся союзом «к тому же», выделяются (или отделяются) запятыми. После слов «к тому же» запятая не ставится.
>
> Меж тем регулировщица, став перед полуторкой, ругала Хижняка, несомненного виновника затора, к тому же не желавшего осаживать назад, за обочину, на арестную площадку, как она требовала. В. Богомолов, Момент истины. Правда, у нас читают редко Евангелие, к тому же народ наш темный, неграмотный…. М. Пришвин, Мирская чаша. К тому же каждый день шел снег, и каждое утро приходилось, прежде чем приступить к самой работе, порядочно поработать лопатой. М. Пришвин, Серая Сова.
>
> @ Обороты со словами «и к тому же» обычно не обособляются. Не ябедничать же на Зефирку, тварь бессловесную и к тому же, как выяснилось, нескверную сердцем. Б. Акунин, Внеклассное чтение. Слегка, приятно опьянев и ободренный к тому же Зосиной приветливостью, я начал поглядывать на нее чуть длительнее... В. Богомолов, Зося.

По поводу предложения "Я, к тому же, хорошо играю на пианино" мое мнение отличается от @Dafnija. Я думаю, что запятая не нужна. Подобный вопрос задавали Грамоте:

> [Вопрос № 297298](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=297298)
> здравствуйте. нужны ли запятые : а это, к тому же, приводит к
> Ответ справочной службы русского языка
> Указанные запятые не нужны.

Comment: Авторское обособление возможно. Обособляется в случае, когда союз **к тому же** выступает в качестве вводного сочетания с целью обратить внимание на что-то. В своём справочнике вводных слов О.Д. Фрамполь приводит ряд примеров известных авторов (Бродский, Достоевский, Алексин, Пришвин). Там же сказано, что такое употребление не рекомендуется. Пример от Dafnija без запятых будет иметь несколько другой смысл.