# Нужна ли запятая после "к тому же", стоящего в начале предложения?

Tags: пунктуация

Собственно, сабж. Предложение:

> К тому же они умудрились пересечь
> границу как раз перед рассветом...

Мне предложили поставить запятую, я залезла в интернет проверить, но что-то четкого ответа с похожим примером не нашла

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не нужна.

> Примечание. Не являются вводными и не выделяются запятыми слова и словосочетания: авось, буквально, будто, вдобавок, в довершение, вдруг, ведь, в конечном счете, вот, вряд ли, все-таки, далее, едва ли, исключительно, именно, как будто, как бы, как раз, ***к тому же***, между тем, небось, по предложению, по постановлению, по решению, приблизительно, примерно, притом, почти, поэтому, просто, решительно, словно, якобы и др.

(курсив мой, b-s)
http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/47.htm

А вообще - повтор вопроса.
["К тому же"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/1836/)

Comment: Да, я читала тот пост, но так и не смогла понять, применимо ли в данном случае то, о чем в нем пишется. К тому же меня так настойчиво пытаются заставить поставить там эту запятую...
Спасибо!

Comment: Там пишется о том, что оборот, присоединяемый с "помощью к тому же" обособляется запятыми, но сам союз "к тому же" от такого оборота не отделяется.    
А у вас даже присоединямого оборота нет, "к тому же" относится к главному предложению (оно же единственное).  
Иногда возможно, конечно, авторское интонационное обособление, но тут я даже для него причин не вижу.

Я в ответе ссылочку добавил на конкретное правило.